# nested queries with supabase rls

Tags: supabase, row-level-security

I use supabase as a db, and I would like to enable rls, but I worry about nested data:

Say I have the following tables, nested in this way:

```
Orgs
  Users
  Spaces
    Projects
      Notes
        Comments
```

Now an Org admin may create a new Space and invite Users from their Org. I get that I can make a SpacesMemberships table and use joins to authorise users to specific Spaces, like described [here](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/row-level-security#using-joins).

Now, if someone wants to create a Post or a Comment, they can only do that in Spaces of which they are a member.

The Posts and Comments don't have a Space FK since they are nested to Spaces through Projects. **(Or Should they have a Space FK for auth reasons?)**

**How do I create a Row Level Security Policy that ensures that any table nested under Spaces follows the same members based rules as their (grand-) parent Space?**